# ICEauthority problem I am not able to start my laptop

Tags: boot, tty

So I have a problem,I cannot start my laptop because when I want to log in it shows me error: "Could not update ICEauthority file/home/frane/.ICEauthority.Then I log out and I tried a several things in terminal but nothing helps.Btw when I write command and I hit enter right away it ask me a password and I am unable to write command in totally.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to switch to the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1), try `ls -la` to see whether you are permitted to edit the .ICEauthority file. The output should look like this:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user user  6682 Jan  6 00:02 .ICEauthority
```

If it doesn't, try executing the following:

```
sudo chmod 644 .ICEauthority
```

Then try again to log in.